# Is terminal velocity applicable in the horizontal plane?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, drag

Is there a speed that object A can move at, such that object B would remain 'stuck' to the front of object A, due only to the air pressure as a factor of object A's speed?

I realise that friction between object A and B play a part, and that the shape of both objects could affect things, so how about both A and B are two halves of the same sphere made from the same material?

To clarify my use of the term terminal velocity, I mean that there's a speed, at which the opposing forces balance out.

Asking for a friend!